# select from database take lot of time using php

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data email of subscribers. Here's what I'm doing:

```
select
  email
from
  data_list
where
  email NOT IN (
     select
        email_subscribe
     from
       subscribe
  )
```

This takes a lot of time. Any suggestions on how to improve it?

data_list= 50.000 email

subscribe table = 10 million email

Comment: Post the results off `EXPLAIN [query]`

Comment: what do you mean by "a lot of time"? You have a lot of entries, so that's not surprising. I've seen examples in SO where requests took more than 24h, all is relative..

Comment: What is `perl` doing in the tags list here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [`explain query plan`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) will give you the best direction.

However, judging solely from the query itself, the very first thing that you should check is that you have an [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on the `data_list.email` column and on `subscribe.email_subscribe`.

Another thing that you could try do, is turn your `IN` into a `JOIN`. The MySQL optimizer may already do this for you, but there's the chance that it's turning all 10 million rows from subscribe into multiple `OR`.

```
select
  d.email
from
  data_list d
  left join subscribe s
    on (d.email=s.email_subscribe)
where
  s.email_subscribe is null
```

Comment: i hadn't heard of `explain` before, that's useful! I actually ran a little couple of tests before i wanted to add this exact answer, old school ways (feeling suddenly old). Based on 2 small email tables and running the queries 10000 times, i actually found 3.02 seconds for the OP request, and 2.78 seconds for this one. definetly faster (both tables have an index of course)

Comment: @kadd Yeah, retrieving a query plan is very useful for optimizing queries. It's difficult to estimate if this new query would actually perform better, because the optimizer might behave differently depending on how much data it will have to work with. For example, if the "subscribe" table is fairly small, the optimizer might think it better to turn it into OR statements (even though your test showed `IN` was slower). But in the OP's case, the optimizer might decide that it's best to turn the `in` into a `left join` on its own, due to the number of rows. But who knows (without a query plan)! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following query instead. Make sure that both **data_list.email** and **subscribe.email_subscribe** are indexed in their tables to have better performance:

```
SELECT data_list.email
FROM data_list LEFT JOIN subscribe ON subscribe.email_subscribe = data_list.email
WHERE subscribe.email_subscribe IS NULL
```

Comment: it works thanks all